# Linking Cocoapods as shared iOS 8 Library

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios8, ios-app-extension

iOS 8 introduced a feature to allow for shared frameworks in the application sandbox. This is especially useful when using extensions alongside the main application.

Statically linking Cocoapods in both the main application and the extension seems like a non-optimal solution. How do I link Cocoapods as a shared framework to be used by both my Extension(s) and the main application using Xcode?

Comment: iOS 8 wasn't out a week ago. Let the cocoapods folks handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a active development branch will support implement Pod in swift. That will also support build pods as new Dynamic Library and link against.

See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2222

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods 0.36 now supports frameworks and swift. http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/